# Command CompileXIB failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the problem when building ios app using Xcode. That was going well before while building the project. Idk why it appears something weird on the error message. There is nothing wrong with my code actually.

The error message said to look like this:

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bVDU.png)

> CompileXIB /Users/saiful/Documents/test-ios/test/test/Base.lproj/RoomResultTableViewCell.xib (in target: test)
>       cd /Users/saiful/Documents/test-ios/test
>       export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --module test --output-partial-info-plist /Users/saiful/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-bgtolzqqziiyvkfqjgwogitynwsj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Base.lproj/RoomResultTableViewCell-PartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --target-device iphone --minimum-deployment-target 9.0 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/saiful/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-bgtolzqqziiyvkfqjgwogitynwsj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.app/Base.lproj/RoomResultTableViewCell.nib /Users/saiful/Documents/test-ios/test/test/Base.lproj/RoomResultTableViewCell.xib

But when I tried to build again the error message will throw the other XIB or storyboard name.

I already tried to clean and rebuild. Also, remove the derived data and reopen my Xcode. **Anw I'm using git for my project**. Is that something missed out while I'm moving to another branch?

Comment: even i got same issue, while running objective c project in xcode 11.1 & BigSur OS. Did you found any solution, let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the first tab of attribute inspector. 
Scroll to section Interface builder document section. 
From the drop down try changing the Xcode version from Opens in drop down.

[image]

Comment: Ya it set from the beginning. And still appear the build failed

Comment: When upgrading to Xcode 11 I had only one XIB file (of many in my project) that failed to compile with the "Command CompileXIB failed with a nonzero exit code" error. Changing the "Opens In" Xcode version from Xcode 10 to Xcode 11 fixed this problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the structure of the XIB differs from the structure that Xcode is expecting. This could have been caused by an update of Xcode.
@ayon.gupta 's answer should change the structure of the xib to what your current Xcode needs. I've noticed that in some beta versions of Xcode the beta version is not in the dropdown so that could be your case.

Comment: can you suggest, how to change xib format according to xcode ?